# CSS position:fixed element and margins

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a sticky searchbox so that it's always at the top of the page when you scroll.
However, I'd like it to take up 100% of the container, not the window.

Here's an HTML markup example:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="searchbox">
        Search Box
    </div>
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
.container {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 20px;
    height: 40px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.searchbox {
    background-color: red;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Here's a fiddle with what's currently happening: http://jsfiddle.net/09ynr879/

I'd like it to be indented on the right side by the same amount it already is on the left. Any way to fix this? I'd like to be evenly in the center with the same margins on the left and on the right.

Thanks in advance.

Here's a screenshot of the actual site where we're having the problem:
http://s2.postimg.org/dlj47yqix/Screen_Shot_2014_10_06_at_11_08_24_AM.png

Notice how the searchbox starts at the right place but ends at the end of the page, not at the end of the container. We're using Bootstrap 3.2

Answer (score 3):

Elements that are `position: fixed` have no relative parents.  They are always going to be fixed relative to the page.

If it's no problem to you, remove `position: fixed;` from `.searchbox` and add it to `.container`

Comment: Thanks for the answer! That creates the appropriate margins of the searchbox, but the searchbox is no longer sticky.

Comment: This makes the whole container sticky, not just the searchbox. Did you want the container to stay and only the searchbox to move?

Comment: I need the container to be able to scroll, but the searchbox to stick to the top.

Comment: There isn't a way, that I know of, where you could do that in just CSS.  JS will have to be involved.

Comment: Take a look at the screenshot I've added on my first post, maybe it makes it more clear. Really would rather not fallback to JS on this one

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible, the fixed position get's out of the flow.

But an alternative solution:

```
.container {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 20px;
    height: 40px;
    position: fixed;
}

.searchbox {
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/09ynr879/4/

Answer (score 0):

Position fixed is always of the entire window. If you want to do it for just a container, you need JavaScript.

I think what you are looking for is either:

StickyMojo or jQuery Stickem

Bootstrap has a similar thing, called Affix.